# count records in datasource - c#

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, datasource

I want to show a message on the screen if a search returns no records in a datasource, just not sure of the syntax,

eg

```
if(gridview.datasource.[number of records] = 0)
{
 do a thing
}
```

or evaluate the linq query behind the datasource,

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Rows collection of the gridview.

```
if(gridview.Rows.Count == 0)
{
 do a thing
}
```

Comment: No, only rows of DataControlRowType.DataRow are included in Rows collection : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Rows will only give you the *current* page of rows if paging is enabled.

Comment: that worked just fine thanks, can you do somthing similar with a DataList I wonder?

Comment: Yes, but it is a little bit different: DataList contains an Items collection which contains all types of rows. You probably want to count only rows that are bound to data, and not to count Header, Footer... Try var MyRowCount = MyDataList.Items.Cast<DataListItem>().Count(d => d.ItemType == ListItemType.Item);

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast your datasource to the correct type that it is bound to. Just using rows will not always give you the total count in the datasource. Look at this example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3">
</asp:GridView>
```

And in code behind:

```
var fruit = new List<string>() 
    { "banana", "orange", "apple", "strawberry", "melon", "grape" }

GridView1.DataSource = fruit;
GridView1.DataBind();

int rowsCount = GridView1.Rows.Count; // rowsCount = 3

int dataCount = ((List<string>)GridView1.DataSource).Count; // dataCount = 6
```

So you can see that just counting the rows only returns '3', since paging is enabled. This is the count of the current page of rows. However, casting the datasource gives you the count returned by the original datasource. So you can use either so long as you understand the difference.

Comment: Thanks for that, useful for the future, not needing paging in thes project though but that will come in handy